# How can I Render ONLY the Alpha Channel

Tags: transparency

I can't find the way to render Only the Alpha channel of a very simple scene. I have only a letter that moves in the center of the cam (see attachment).

the problem is, I can set the Alpha channel with objectID and render the pass, but I need ONLY the Alpha pass exporting as tif or jpg. Not the whole image as a channel!

My second problem is that blender is rendering the whole scene, and it takes very long time. Can I say to blender, "Please, render only the Mask, not the light rays?"

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: There is no way to render only a pass without rendering the combined pass.

Comment: you could render as PNG with alpha, then disable the lights and switch to eevee, that would speed up rendering time a lot